# How to make PHP call Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form and two modals in HTML, in PHP I made a function to check if the domain exists and finally, in AJAX, I have a small function in `.done`, but the problem is there. I want that, if PHP returns 1, the javascript shows the 'AvailableModal' modal to the user, and if it returns 0, show the 'UnavailableModal'. But PHP only returns 1 or 0 and javascript does nothing.

HTML:

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="p-3 form-control form-control-lg mb-2 mr-sm-2 input-ro www" id="inlineFormInputName2" name="www." value="www." placeholder="www." readonly>

    <div class="input-group justify-content-center mb-2 mr-sm-2">
        <input type="text" name="domain" id="domain" class="input-dom form-control form-control-lg">
    </div>

    <div class="form-check mb-2 mr-sm-2 select-padding">
        <select name="point" id="point">
            <option value=".com">.com</option>
            <option value=".com.br">.com.br</option>
            <option value=".net">.net</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="salvar-form" class="btn btn-dominio btn-outline-danger" name="send" value="Send">
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade hide" id="availableModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="TituloModalCentralizado" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Domain Available!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade hide" id="unavailableModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="TituloModalCentralizado" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Domain unavailable!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#salvar-form").click(function(e) {
        const www = $('.www').val();
        const domain = $('#domain').val();
        const com = $('#point').val();
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "domain-register.php",
                data: {
                    www: www,
                    domain: domain,
                    com: com
                },
            })
            .done(function(dominio) {
                if (dominio == 1) {
                    $('#availableModal').modal("show");
                } else if (dominio == 0) {
                    $('#unavailableModal').modal("show");
                }
            })
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $dominio = $_POST['www'] . $_POST['domain'] . $_POST['com'];
    function dominio_disponivel($dominio)
    {
        if (checkdnsrr($dominio, 'ANY') && gethostbyname($dominio) != $dominio)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    if (dominio_disponivel($dominio))
        echo 1;
    else
        echo 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: what value do you get back in the `done` function? Is `dominio` an integer or string or other?

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Figure out what `dominio` actually is (e.g. ```console.log(` [${dominio}]`)```, typeof dominio.

Comment: It is returning the PHP result (1 or 0) and the entire HTML code.

https://prnt.sc/s1y7aw

Comment: you are posting to the same page? the response your AJAX callback is getting is(in this case) `0` and then some HTML - this invalidates the logic in the `done` callback because the response is neither 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you should make the response from php as a json, like

```
if(...)
  $res = ['status'=>true];
else
  $res = ['status'=>false];

return json_encode($res);
```

and in javascript parse the json respon

```
.done(function(dominio){
    var res = $.parseJSON(dominio);
    if(res.status){
      // show modal a
    }else{
      // show modal b
    }
})
```

I'm not sure, may be jquery treat the response as text, that why boolean comparing doesn't work

Comment: I touched on some points like: I changed `res.status` to `res == 1` and `res == 0` in the if clause of `.done`. But your answer worked, thank you!